# How to change placerholder in newsletter prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, newsletter

I'm having trouble changing the text for the newsletter. It says "Your email address". I can't change it anywhere, any suggestions?

Prestashop ver 1.7.5.2

```
<input class="newsletter-input form-control" id="newsletter-input-footer" type="email" name="email_wdg" placeholder="Your email address" required="required" value="">
```

[image: Photo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default Prestashop newsletter module, you can change it from translations but if you use another module, its (TPL) files should be checked.